# Database schema for product prices which can change daily

Tags: sql-server, rules

I am looking for suggestions to design a database schema based on following requirements.

1. Product can have variant
2. each variant can have different price
3. Price can be different for specific day of a week
4. Price can be different for a specific time of the day
5. all prices will have validity for specific dates only
6. Prices can be defined for peak, high or medium seasons
7. Suppliers offering any product can define their own prices and above rules still applies

what could be best possible schema where data is easy to retrieve without impacting performance?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Regards
Harmeet

Comment: Do you need to store the data historically?

Comment: This is both entirely too broad and primarily opinion based. There are a zillion possibilities for how to design such a database. If you are so uncertain as to even begin I would suggest you should hire a consultant because designing the database with no clue how to do it is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO isn't really a forum for suggestions as much as answers. No answer anyone gives can be definitively correct. With that said, I would keep the tables as granular as possible to allow for easy changes across products.

In regards to #5, I would place start and end dates on products. If the price is no-longer valid, the product should no longer be available.

This includes relations for different seasonal prices, however you would either need to hardcode the seasons or create another table to define those.

For prices, if this is more than 1 region you may want a regions table in which case a currency column would be appropriate.

This is operational data, not temporal data. If you want it available for historical analysis of pricing you would need to create temporal tables as well.

Product Table

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| ProductName | ProductID | ProductStartDate | ProductEndDate |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| Product1    |         1 | 01/01/2017       | 01/01/2018     |
| Product2    |         2 | 01/01/2017       | 01/01/2018     |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
```

Variant Table

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| ProductID | VariantID | VariantName | NormalPriceID | HighPriceID | PeakPriceID |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 |         1 | Blue        |             1 |           3 |           5 |
|         1 |         2 | Black       |             2 |           4 |           5 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Price Table

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| PriceID | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|       1 |  30 |  30 |  30 |  30 |  35 |  35 |  35 |
|       2 |  35 |  35 |  35 |  35 |  40 |  40 |  40 |
|       3 |  33 |  33 |  33 |  33 |  39 |  39 |  39 |
|       4 |  38 |  38 |  38 |  38 |  44 |  44 |  44 |
|       5 |  40 |  40 |  40 |  40 |  50 |  50 |  50 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```